# How to refer to an element with an id in dropmenu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Please help me with this script. I'm trying to link some php code to a dropdown menu, but I get no reaction....

The code is:

js code:

```
function loadDoc1() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("show2").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET","user_manag.php",true);
        xhttp.send();
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#a2").click(function() {
            $("#show2")".load("user_manag.php",function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
                if(statusTxt == "success")
                    alert("External content loaded successfully!");
                if(statusTxt == "error")
                    alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
            });
        });
    });
```

HTML markup:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="border:4px solid white">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header" style="margin-top:5px;">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button> 
      <a href="http://www.april-romania.ro"><img src="logo1.jpg" style="width:40px;height:40px;"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>Search</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">ADMIN
          <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a id="a1" href="#" action="loadDoc1()">User management</a></li>
            <li><button id="button1">User management</button></li>
            <li><a id="a2" href="#">Log report</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Change caseID</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Code tables</a></li>  
          </ul>
        </li>  
</div>
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
  <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-sm-1 sidenav" style="border: 4px solid white";>

    </div>

    <div id="show2" class="col-sm-8 text-left" style="background-color:rgb(200,200,200);border: 4px solid white; height: 100%">
            hereeeeeeeeee

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 sidenav" style="background-color:gray;border: 4px solid white">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

user_manag.php is:

```
<?php

echo "user management";

?>
```

I'm trying to change content in `<div>#swow2` when I access one of the menu links.... I tried with ajax, with js, with jQuery, with attribute action, `onclick`, with links, buttons.... nothing seems to work. I think it doesn't recognize the ids I gave to the 'a' or 'button' elements in the menu.

Comment: looks like maybe a syntax error: `$("#show2")".load` has an extra `"` before `.load`. not sure if that's causing the issue

Comment: thank you. i made the jquery to work after proper syntax, i figured it out that something is wrong in the js function and I abandoned the js function

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your HTML has several **missing closing tags**. You also have an error in the JS as pointed in the comment. Here is the clean script (now it works):

HTML & JS

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="border:4px solid white">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header" style="margin-top:5px;">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button> 
      <a href="http://www.april-romania.ro"><img src="logo1.jpg" style="width:40px;height:40px;"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>Search</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">ADMIN<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a id="a1" href="#" action="loadDoc1()">User management</a></li>
            <li><button id="button1">User management</button></li>
            <li><a id="a2" href="#">Log report</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Change caseID</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Code tables</a></li>  
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>  
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
  <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-sm-1 sidenav" style="border: 4px solid white"></div>
    <div id="show2" class="col-sm-8 text-left" style="background-color:rgb(200,200,200);border: 4px solid white; height: 100%">
            hereeeeeeeeee
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 sidenav" style="background-color:gray;border: 4px solid white"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function loadDoc1() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("show2").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET","user_manag.php",true);
        xhttp.send();
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#a2").click(function() {
            $("#show2").load("user_manag.php",function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
                if(statusTxt == "success")
                    alert("External content loaded successfully!");
                if(statusTxt == "error")
                    alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```